# Why is doDebug() giving me this error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder, box2d

I just started out with FlashPunk and I'm using Flash Builder as my IDE on Mac.

I set up FlashPunk with Box2D and box2fp, and I've been trying to build a really simplistic game. But my problem is, when I run doDebug() I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at net.box2fp::Box2DWorld/debug_draw()[/Users/samirghobril/Desktop/MusicGame/src/net/box2fp/Box2DWorld.as:103]
at net.box2fp::Box2DWorld/doDebug()[/Users/samirghobril/Desktop/MusicGame/src/net/box2fp/Box2DWorld.as:123]
at Level1()[/Users/samirghobril/Desktop/MusicGame/src/Level1.as:13]
at Main()[/Users/samirghobril/Desktop/MusicGame/src/Main.as:18]
```

Here's Main.as:

```
package
{

    import net.box2fp.Box2DWorld;
    import net.flashpunk.Engine;
    import net.flashpunk.FP;
    import net.flashpunk.Screen;

    [SWF(width='800',height='600',backgroundColor='#ffffff',frameRate='60')]

    public class Main extends Engine
    {
        public function Main()
        {

            super(800, 600, Box2DWorld.DEFAULT_FRAMERATE, true);

            FP.world = new Level1;


        }

        override public function init():void
        {
            FP.console.enable();
            FP.world = new Level1;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's Level1.as:

```
package
{
    import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;

    import net.box2fp.Box2DWorld;

    public class Level1 extends Box2DWorld
    {
        public function Level1()
        {
            super();
            setGravity(new b2Vec2(0, 10));
            doDebug();
        }

        override public function begin():void
        {
            add(new Player(80, 600));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's Player.as:

```
package
{
    import Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body;

    import net.box2fp.Box2DEntity;
    import net.box2fp.Box2DShapeBuilder;

    public class Player extends Box2DEntity
    {
        public function Player(x:Number=0, y:Number=0, w:uint=1, h:uint=1, b2Type:int=0)
        {
            super(x, y, 30, 60, b2Body.b2_dynamicBody);
        }

        override public function buildShapes(friction:Number, density:Number, restitution:Number, group:int, category:int, collmask:int):void
        {
            Box2DShapeBuilder.buildRectangle(body, width / (2.0 * box2dworld.scale), height / (2.0 * box2dworld.scale));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you update your code as follows your project should compile.

Main.as:

```
package
{

    import net.box2fp.Box2DWorld;

    import net.flashpunk.Engine;
    import net.flashpunk.FP;
    import net.flashpunk.Screen;

    [SWF(width='800',height='600',backgroundColor='#ffffff',frameRate='60')]

    public class Main extends Engine
    {
        public function Main()
        {
            super(800, 600, Box2DWorld.DEFAULT_FRAMERATE, true);

            FP.console.enable();
            FP.world = new Level1();
        }

        override public function init():void
        {
            trace("FlashPunk has initialised");
        }
    }
}
```

Level1.as:

```
package
{
    import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;

    import net.box2fp.Box2DWorld;

    public class Level1 extends Box2DWorld
    {
        public function Level1()
        {
            super();
            setGravity(new b2Vec2(0, 10));
        }

        override public function begin():void
        {
            doDebug();
            add(new Player(80, 600));
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: The doDebug method attempts to add a Sprite to the FP.stage instance which doesn't exist when the constructor of your Main class is called (and by extension the constructor of your Level1 class which calls the method).

If the above doesn't suit, you could create your world in the init method of your Main class. This method is called by the super class when FlashPunk has successfully initialised (see [this tutorial](http://flashpunk.net/2011/05/the-basics/)). Having looked at the documentation, however, it looks like worlds are conventionally created in the constructor of the main class.

Also, though legal (I think), it's not considered terribly good practice to omit the brackets after calls to new when instantiating a class eg.

Do this:

```
FP.world = new Level1();
```

Not this:

```
FP.world = new Level1;
```